# In Rails, how can I easily reset all records to the default attribute values declared in the model files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I have some tables that use single-table inheritance, and a considerable number of model files for each table. Each model file has some default attributes set, like this:

```rb
class SpecialWidget < Widget
  attribute :name, :string, default: "A Thing"
  attribute :description, :text, default: "This is an awfully special widget."
end
```

This is useful because in my case, the `name` and `description` are unchangeable by end users, so this is a good way for me to set values that I can still change if I need to. Now I can just do `SpecialWidget.create` all I want, and the created `SpecialWidget` will have that default `name` and `description`.

**Now, what I want to be able to do is** update the `name` or `description` of one or more types of `Widget` by changing the value in the model file, like this:

```rb
class SpecialWidget < Widget
  attribute :name, :string, default: "A Thing"
  attribute :description, :text, default: "This is a new description for this widget."
end
```

... and then running some sort of command via script or Rails console to reset every `Widget`'s `name` and `description` in the database to their default values. It should not reset values for which I haven't declared a default.

This *must* be done via a default declaration in the code, and not by setting default values in the database schema, since I am using STI, and each model will have a different `name` and `description`.

Comment: If this cannot be modified, it never should have gone in the database. Why not simply have `def name; "A thing"; end`?

Comment: @meagar Great question. That's exactly what I did, and liked it, until I read that doing that would prevent me from being able to do nice Active Record things with `name` and `description`, like sorting and paging. If I want to query against a constant method, I need to do `Widget.all` and then sort "manually". Is that not the case?

Comment: You wouldn't query against values you know are constants across classes, You would query based on something variable within each record, like `type`. So, if you know that all `SubClass` models have a `def name; "A Thing"; end`, and you want to find all records with `name` equal to `A Thing`, you would just do `SubClass.all`.

Comment: @meagar Okay, but what if I wanted to get all `Widget`s sorted by `name`? In that case, I'd have to pull everything into memory with `Widget.all` and then sort outside of AR, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for some magic way to do this, when in reality it can be done simply if you accept that a simple soluton is okay.

For example, this would be for one of the models, `SpecialWallet`:

```
new_default_desc = "This is a new description for this widget."
Wallet.where.not(
  description: new_default_desc
).update_all(
  description: new_default_desc
)
```

You would repeat this process for the other models and columns.

Comment: Yeah, I thought maybe there was a special way to just say "reset to attribute defaults", but since it doesn't seem like there is, just using simple updates like this works.